# custom loss function not working properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a convolutional neural network which predicts one label. I want to ignore loss resulted from some predictions during training. I wrote a custom binary cross entropy loss function for this. I want to ignore the loss when y_true=999.

```
def custom_loss_mask(y_true, y_pred):
     y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=y_pred.dtype)

     idx_ = (y_true!=999)
     idx = tf.cast(idx_, dtype=y_pred.dtype)

     loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true*idx, y_pred*idx)

     return loss
```

I tested out the model for 10 epochs but the loss function does not seem to be working ie., the val_loss is not changing over the epochs and I am getting a 0.5 AUC (Area under ROC curve).

```
Epoch 1/10
26/26 [==============================] - 11s 179ms/step - loss: 1.3587 - accuracy: 0.9106 - val_loss: 1.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9185
Epoch 2/10
26/26 [==============================] - 4s 159ms/step - loss: 1.2572 - accuracy: 0.9185 - val_loss: 1.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9185
Epoch 3/10
26/26 [==============================] - 4s 158ms/step - loss: 1.2572 - accuracy: 0.9185 - val_loss: 1.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9185
Epoch 4/10
26/26 [==============================] - 4s 158ms/step - loss: 1.2572 - accuracy: 0.9185 - val_loss: 1.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9185
Epoch 5/10
26/26 [==============================] - 4s 158ms/step - loss: 1.2572 - accuracy: 0.9185 - val_loss: 1.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9185
Epoch 6/10
26/26 [==============================] - 4s 158ms/step - loss: 1.2572 - accuracy: 0.9185 - val_loss: 1.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9185
Epoch 7/10
26/26 [==============================] - 4s 159ms/step - loss: 1.2572 - accuracy: 0.9185 - val_loss: 1.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9185
Epoch 8/10
26/26 [==============================] - 4s 159ms/step - loss: 1.2572 - accuracy: 0.9185 - val_loss: 1.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9185
Epoch 9/10
26/26 [==============================] - 4s 160ms/step - loss: 1.2572 - accuracy: 0.9185 - val_loss: 1.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9185
Epoch 10/10
26/26 [==============================] - 4s 159ms/step - loss: 1.2572 - accuracy: 0.9185 - val_loss: 1.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9185
testing
**********Testing model**********
training AUC : 0.5
testing AUC : 0.5
```

Some more information on the experiment, I am using an Adam optimizer with 1e-4 learning rate. I am using a data generator for training the model and I a training my model with model.fit_generator().

Does anyone see any mistakes regarding this?
If yes, what might be the possible fix?

Comment: When you say 10 labels, do you mean 10 different classes? Because then binary crossentropy would not make much sense as a loss there.

Comment: Yeah 10 different classes. That is why I am using binary cross entropy but my ground truth has some missing labels. What is the correct way to mask it is my query?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy the problem should me more clear now. Really would appreciate the help

Comment: Binary cross-entropy expects 0-1 labels, you cannot have a label with a value of 999, you probably want to mask according to class indices in the last dimension.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy that is exactly what I am trying to do. The above code is correct according that logic but it does not seem to be working

Comment: No, it is not correct, because a label of 999 is not valid to pass to your loss.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy but those 999 values are getting masked by the loss function. You can see I have multiplied it with and idx tensor which basically contains information about which all values are not 999 in my y_true and y_pred

Comment: Sure but what are the actual values of your labels? Since these have to be one-hot encoded, I am not sure how you put 999 in there.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy the features are encoded as 0 or 1. But there are some cases where it is 999. Those cases should be ignored while calculating the loss